# Moment js, React: Month rendering problem

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

My calendar renders initial month succesfully but after clicking next or previous months it won't render the new month and or any month after that. My guess is that it either is a render problem or there is still something with moment.js that I'm not aware of. I've tried using different ways to let **CalendarComponents** know that there has been a change in **CurrentMonth** (so that it would need to re-render), latest of these tries is **memoizedValue**.

In my mind it is either that rendering issue or something with moment.js that I'm not seeing at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useMemo } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import moment from 'moment';

const App = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        currentMonth: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        currentWeek: moment().weeks(),
        selectedDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        startDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });


    const renderHeader = () => {


        return (
            <div className="header row flex-middle">
                <div className="col col-start">
                    <div className="icon" onClick={prevMonth}>
                        Previous month
          </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col col-center">
                    <span>{moment(state.currentMonth).clone().format('MMMM-YYYY')}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="col col-end" onClick={nextMonth}>
                    <div className="icon">Next month</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    const renderWeekDays = () => {
        const days = [];
        const weekDays = moment.weekdays();

        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            days.push(
                <div className="col col-center" key={i}>
                    {weekDays[i]}
                </div>
            );
        };

        return <div className="days row">{days}</div>;
    }

    const renderCells = () => {
        const monthStart = moment(state.currentMonth).clone().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        const monthEnd = moment(monthStart).clone().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        const startDate = moment(monthStart).clone().startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        const endDate = moment(monthEnd).clone().endOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD');



        console.log(endDate);

        const rows = [];

        let days = [];
        let day = startDate;
        console.log(day);
        let formattedDate = "";

        while (day <= endDate) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                formattedDate = moment(day).format('DD');
                const cloneDay = day;
                days.push(
                    <div
                        className={`col cell ${
                            !moment(day).isSame(monthStart, 'month')
                                ? "disabled"
                                : null
                            }`}
                        key={day}
                    >
                        <span className="number">{formattedDate}</span>
                    </div>
                );
                day = moment(day).add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            }
            rows.push(
                <div className="row" key={day}>
                    {days}
                </div>
            );
            days = [];
        }
        return <div className="body">{rows}</div>;
    }


    const nextMonth = () => {
        setState({
            currentMonth: moment(state.currentMonth).add(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        });
    };

    const prevMonth = () => {
        setState({
            currentMonth: moment(state.currentMonth).subtract(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        });
    };


    const CalendarComponents = ({ date }) => {

        const monthCalendar = () => {

            return (
                <div className="calendar" style={{ height: '1000px' }}>
                    {renderHeader()}
                    {renderWeekDays()}
                    {renderCells()}
                </div>
            )
        };

        const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => monthCalendar(), [state.currentMonth]);



        return memoizedValue;

    }


    const handleDate = (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    }


    return (
        <div className="calendar" style={{ height: '1000px' }}>
            <CalendarComponents />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you logged to make sure that the state is actually updating?

Comment: Appears to be a render issue because when I use moment just like this on my machine it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Yes, currentMonth is updated whenever clicking 'next month' or 'previous month' and it correctly console.logs that new month. If it indeed is rendering issue I wonder how I would get it to update correctly when changing months? Thanks again.

Comment: I ran your code without the css file (since I dont have it) and it works for me. Clicking on next/prev month changes the month

Comment: Oh, now that's interesting. Now that I tested it like so without the css it actually does seem to work. That is great! Sorry that it wasn't much of a challenge to crack but I'm very grateful as I wouldn't have guessed that css would cause so much trouble in this case so I've been looking for answers elsewhere. Thank you so much for taking the time in assisting me on this :)

Comment: I also find that very strange! Never heard of something like that happening before I am interested to know what is causing it.

Comment: I traced the problem to this particular bit in the css file:

.calendar .body .col {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 7);
  width: calc(100% / 7);
**height: calc(100& / 7);**
}

earlier when I wanted those columns to scale in height (I need to fill calendar days with certain amount of boxes depending on user) I used **height: calc(100% / 7);** and when pressing next or previous it would destroy the view. It was an earlier test to see what happens but was forgotten there in the css file. When I removed that it started working correctly. Thank you so much for all of your help!